# DJANGO - create a form that has as many inputs as there is data in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to django and I'm building a webapp that manages a db (created by django) where I'm going to save the data of a company with its employees etc.
Each entity has its own model in models.py.
Creating the page to be able to modify the data that is already inserted in the db, I encountered a problem: taking into account that a person can have more than one telephone number, in the form to insert the modified data I should have more inputs, dynamically generated by the view. py of django, based on how many phone numbers have been saved in the db.
I've been stuck on this problem for hours and I can't find a solution ;)

I saw someone using this function in view.py but it doesn't seem to work for me.

`form = formset_factory(modifyPeopleForm, extra=1)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formSet = form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
else:
    numbers= phoneNumbers.objects.filter(people=people_istance.id)
    formset = form(initial=[{
        'name': personale_istance.nome,
        'secondName': personale_istance.cognome,
        'job': personale_istance.mansione,
        'phoneNumber': number.number} for number in numbers]
    )`
```